# Dynamic calculation numbers of points in polygon QField

Tags: expression, point-in-polygon, qfield

I looking for solution of dynamic calculating number of points in polygon on the go and changing color of polygon if there are specified number of point.

I have 2 layers in project. One polygon, one with points. Points are empty and get collected by the QField. I have a constant number to collect each one polygon (ex.20). Is there any option to do this with expression?

I found only a process in QGIS with calculating points in polygon but it's only static and unavailable on QField.

Do you have any idea?

---

[image]

[image]

I have information about error.

If I want count ex. 20 point in polygon then I must in "expression" type "=>20" ?

If I do something wrong I'm sorry. I'm dumb in expression.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a rule-based renderer with an `aggregate` expression:

1. Create a new class for the polygons with a color of your choice.
2. Use this as its filter expression, adjust the layer:

```
aggregate(
  layer:='NAME/ID OF YOUR POINT LAYER'
  aggregate:='count',
  expression:='',
  filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)) 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use data driven override for the color of the polygons and select Assistant. Set the source to the expression `array_length(overlay_intersects ('name_of_point_layer', $id))`. Select values from/to and a color ramp.

Now, if a polygon contains the number of points set in `Values from`, it is rendered in the color on the left of the ramp; with the value definee in `Values to` with the color on the right and intermediate values the respective colors in between.

*Number of yellow points per polygon defines its color:*
[image]